# Why is text wrapping when zooming page?

Tags: html, css, text, stylesheet, word-wrap

I have this code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

#body {
  width: 1040px;
  height: 1319px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

#header {
  width: 76%;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

#header #logo {
  width: 49%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

#header #logo img {
  float: left;
}

#header #logo p {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #aeaeae;
}

#header #login {
  width: 51%;
  height: 79px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

#header #login form {
  padding: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #DCDCDC), color-stop(1, #F3F3F3));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #DCDCDC 0%, #F3F3F3 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #DCDCDC 0%, #F3F3F3 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #DCDCDC 0%, #F3F3F3 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #DCDCDC 0%, #F3F3F3 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #DCDCDC 0%, #F3F3F3 100%);
  margin-top: 38px;
}

#header #login form input[type="text"],
#header #login input[type="password"] {
  width: 98px;
  height: 17px;
}

#header #login form input[type="submit"] {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #F1A62D), color-stop(1, #F56E00));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #F1A62D 0%, #F56E00 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #F1A62D 0%, #F56E00 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #F1A62D 0%, #F56E00 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #F1A62D 0%, #F56E00 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F1A62D 0%, #F56E00 100%);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: white;
  width: 70px;
  height: 22px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

#header #navbar {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: magenta;
  float: left;
}

#sidebar {
  height: 890px;
  width: 24%;
  background-color: brown;
  float: right;
}

#content {
  width: 76%;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}

#footer {
  width: 76%;
  background-color: gold;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="body">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <h1>Sidebar</h1>

    <div id="register"></div>
    <div id="credit"></div>
    <div id="cenik"></div>
    <div id="cards"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="header">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" width="185" height="79">
      <p>aaaaaaa</p>
    </div>
    <div id="login" id="loginBox">
      <form action="#">
        <label for="username">Jméno:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="usernameTxt">
        <label for="password">Heslo:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="passwordTxt">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Přihlásit">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar">
      <h1>Navbar</h1>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Content</h1>

    <div id="reklama"></div>
    <div id="topPanel"></div>
    <div id="botPanel"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    <h1>Footer</h1>

  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that when I zoom out the text near the logo and the Login button wraps. I tried `white-space:nowrap` and `overflow:hidden` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add `white-space:nowrap;` to the css of the `<form>` element itself:

```
#login > form {
     white-space:nowrap;   
}
```

It appears to do what you require (in Chrome, at least :))

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q8ysk30z/

### **Update**

I found a way to resolve things by essentially sticking the form element to the bottom right of its container (`#login`).

```
#login { 
    position: relative; 
}

#login > form { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0; bottom: 0; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/q8ysk30z/2/

Comment: Yes, but when i resize the button conflicts with the Sidebar

Comment: Ah yes I see that now.  It seems fine in Edge..  I shall take a closer look soon (unless someone gets there before me!)

Comment: Now there is another problem :( When i zoom out. the login box runs into the logo

Comment: I can't seem to replicate this in the js fiddle (but the logo isnt loading so maybe that's why).  Is it 184px in width like the html suggests?  (And is this something that was only introduced with the changes I described?)